# How can I paste0 a quotation mark to a string (in a column) in R?

Tags: r, string

I need to analyse a dataset in R that has a column containing a JSON format. In this column, a single ' " '  is missing from the SQL Export which prevents me from applying rJson/JsonLite functions. I want to add the " for the whole column using lapply and paste/paste0-functions but their definition won't let me to.

Is there any simple way to add a single " in a string (on a certain position)?

`A <- paste0(""","id")` doesn't work.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to escape it `paste0("\"", "id")` or wrap it with single tick `paste0('"', 'id')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <- "test"

paste0('"',x,'"')
```

doublequets `"` wrapped in single quetes `'`

Comment: Thanks! You're right concerning the quetes, but how can I use this to drop an " on a specific position, e.g. 2nd? The functions sub/gsub can't help me either. I just need to have ' {"id".. ' instead of ' {id".. ' for the whole column. - EDIT: Got it, I can always use ' ' to replace " ", even in the sub/gsub. Thanks